# Arduino C language use toCharArray() not correct

Tags: arduino-c++

I read data from sensor and show to serial monitor like this.

```
  int humidity = dht.readHumidity();
  int temperature = dht.readTemperature();

  
  String place = "My Home";
  if (online)   {
    if (!client.connected()) {
      reconnect();
    }
    client.loop();
    
    String data = "{\"data\": {\"humidity\":" + String(humidity) + ",  \"temperature\":" + String(temperature) + ", \"place\": " +  place + "}}";

    data.toCharArray(msg, (data.length() + 1));
    Serial.println(msg);
```

The output is

```
{"data": {"humidity":60, "temperature":27, "place": My Home}}
{"data": {"humidity":2147483647, "temperature":2147483647, "place": My Home}}
```

After I run code it have no error but the output is not correct and the program will stop after show this output.
If I comment at line `data.toCharArray(msg, (data.length() + 1));` . Then, the program will show the  correct output of temperature and humidity value. How to fix it?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you're forgetting about the "null" byte, needed to terminate a C string?

Comment: Do you mean to tag `java` instead of `c`?

Comment: I think you are using `C++`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the basic `itoa` function. It is included in `stdlib.h`

```
char buf[12]; // "-2147483648\0"
lcd.printIn(itoa(random(1024)-512, buf, 10));
```

[Source : Arduino Playground](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PrintingNumbers/)